# How to test an EJB @Schedule

Tags: testing, ejb, schedule

I am using an EJB schedule to do email daemon task:

```
@Schedule(hour="8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18")
    public void sendExpirationReminders() {
}
```

How can I test these methods on a running server?

I currently use HtmlUnit for most of my testing so I can make real browser requests. But I'm at a loss how to test the inner contents of these daemon methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't.

What some people suggest (which I agree) is to separate the code that does the scheduling with the code that actually performs an operation. If you follow this, you'll have one class that has the `@Schedule` annotation, which only responsibility is to call the class that performs the operation.

Why you can test this? It's easy, you can't mock Date (or the clock) in an application server.

Comment: That's not too bad of an approach. I'll analyze my software and see how plausible that is.

Comment: The crappy part about that is that the EJB that does the @Schedule also has many injected resources such as the MailSender, VelocityEngine, and so on. It really screws me having to separate the logic.

Comment: You could create a class called Cron, with all the @Scheduled methods, and from that class, call the method you already have.